# problems adding <li> into <ul> from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following  where I would like to dynamically add the list elements to it:

```
<ul name='eval-options' class="inputs-list">                                                                                    
</ul>
```

I'm adding the list elements with the following js but it is not working

```
 $("#eval-options ul").append('<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes" value="option1" /><span>Option one</span></label></li>');
```

Comment: `name='eval-options'` needs to be `id='eval-options'`. `#` is an `id` selector.

Comment: Not working?  Fix it, that always works!  You want a more specific answer, ask a more specific question.  Not working *how*?

Comment: Is there an ancestor of the `ul` that has the ID `eval-options`? That's what your selector is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, declare the ul with an `id` of eval-options, instead of a `name`.

```
<ul id='eval-options' class="inputs-list">                                                                                     
</ul>
```

Secondly, the string for your selector should be

```
$('#eval-options')
```

The selector you're currently using:

```
$('#eval-options ul')
```

means "the ul element contained *as a child of* any element with the identifier `eval-options`"

Answer (score 1):

That would be because # reference's an id.  What you want is to find the name (or the class) of your ul.

Change

```
$("#eval-option ul")
```

to

```
$("ul[name=eval-options]")
```

or

```
$(".inputs-list")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id='eval-options' class="inputs-list">                                                                                    
</ul>


 $("#eval-options").append('<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes" value="option1" /><span>Option one</span></label></li>');
```